# Find Inodes And Recover Binary Files From Raw Data

Tags: ext4, dd, forensics, testdisk, foreman

What command do I use to scan a hard drive that has corrupted superblocks to find inodes?

Additionally, what command do I use to write the file data associated with that inode?

My partition was created with dos/mbr.

I've tried testdisk and other programs but they are designed around requiring a search for extensions or magic numbers. Some of my files do not have either. So I need to retrieve all files without discretion.

*In my particular situation I had two partitions on a 128G drive. The physical first was 32G. The second partition took up the remaining of the drive. I mistakenly used dd to write an iso onto the first 3G of the drive. I'm trying to recover the files on the second partition only. So they should not have been touched because I immediately quit using the drive after I made the mistake.*

**TROUBLESHOOTING**

I downloaded Kali Linux and copied it to a usb stick to troubleshoot. I have booted it into forensics mode and I have all the tools available there.

I have followed the comment advice to make a back up. I've done this with:

```
dd if=/dev/sda2 of=/mnt/samsung.img bs=4G status=progress
```

testdisk did find the second partition and has the label correct, but is unable to find any files saying the superblock is corrupted.

Comment: If you have a corrupted parttition, then you probably will not be able to get all files back. In the absence of a backup, you can try something like [ddrescue](.http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html). Trying to do it manually will probably take an eternity. For just a couple of files, you can use something like `debugfs`, but you have to know a fair amount about the filesystem before you can use it at all effectively.

Comment: for ext* `debugfs` can do it but of course - that requires filesystem metadata, and depending on the corruption, at some point it's just not possible anymore. `photorec` goes after magic byte patterns not because it's silly but because that's the only thing you can do once everything else is corrupt

Comment: I was unable to see if debugfs will work on raw data? In other words a non working partition that still contains the inode and corresponding zone data. Do you know how to use it in such a way, if it does?

Comment: @frostschutz I'm under the impression if an inode is not corrupted it has pointers to it's zone data (the file data). So even if a file doesn't have magic numbers or an extension in the inode data shouldn't it still be recoverable?

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify that I believe only the superblock has been damaged, not the actual inodes.

Comment: Was the disk partitioned using mbr aka dos or with gpt? If the latter then you can probably blow away the first MB of the disk and use fdisk. It will find the backup partition table at the end of the disk and write it at the start again. Stuff on the first partition will be be hard to recover, but stuff on the second should be fine.  I would strongly suggest making a copy of the 128GB and working on that copy if at all possible, a 2TB drive is less than $100 where I am and this is not a place where you want to make mistakes.

Comment: I doubt the superblock is damaged, just the partitioning.

Comment: If it was partitioned as MBR then there is a very very good chance testdisk will be able to recover the second partition, but again makes copies and work on a copy.

Comment: I have updated based on comments